# How do I produce a neat Presentation from the Command Line?

Tags: command-line, scripts, libreoffice

I created a script for Ubuntu terminal that generates answers. The answers are copied to a LibreOffice Writer document. There are tables and a desired format for it. All the format will be lost if I overwrite, and I can't append if I don't output first. Is it possible for me to automatically insert the answers inside the tables?

I only have simple code like `cat hostname` to preview the machine hostname. I'm struggling in copying it and pasting. All I want is to know if it is possible to automatically direct the answer inside a table of a LibreOffice Writer document. Sample ODT template is uploaded below.

[image: Sample Template]

Comment: A libre office document is a zipped file. Unzip it. Find the data in the XHTML and you can edit your new content into the document. Zip it back up and open the file. Done it a couple of times. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/841970/edit-libreoffice-files-from-command-line on how to start; that answer uses calc but writer uses the same setup with some more mark-up. Only your own imagination is the limit ;-)

Comment: You may get better answers on this topic on https://ask.libreoffice.org/ (same model but not affiliated with Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>This doesn't answer the question because AFAIK there is no simple way to achieve the goal exactly like OP requests. Instead I show two different approaches to achieve the goal as best as possible.</sub>

As far as I know, the only easily accessible interface between a shell script and tables in GUI office software like LibreOffice is `.csv` –

## a comma-separated values file

This is very simple, but also very basic and doesn't allow for any formatting. Here's a usage example:

```bsh
$ echo -e "heading 01,heading 02\ncell A2,cell B2\ncell A3,cell B3" >a.csv
$ loffice -o a.csv
```

[image: LibreOffice csv 01]

As a `.csv` is a simple text file, you can change the content with every editor, let's use `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed -i 's/cell A2/replaced cell/' a.csv 
$ loffice -o a.csv
```

[image: LibreOffice csv 02]

As stated above, this doesn't allow for *any* formatting besides [all caps](https://practicaltypography.com/all-caps.html), which in your context is not very satisfactory.

---

If you on the one hand want to have simple text files you can easily change with command-line tools, but on the other hand also want to get a beautifully formatted document,

## [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) is for you

I'd create a `template.tex` and mark the lines I'd like to change later with comments LaTeX ignores, e.g. cell coordinates like `%A2`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{System/Client Information} \\
  \midrule
  {\tiny Machine Hostname:}\newline
  dessert's plowhorse %A2
  &
  {\tiny Machine Brand and Model:}\newline
  Thinkpad X240 %B2
  \\
  {\tiny Operating System (Version \& Variant):}\newline
  Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS %A3
  &
  {\tiny Kernel Version\,/\,Update Level:}\newline
  4.10.0-35-generic %B3
  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Compiled this looks like:

[image: LaTeX example 01]

At the beginning of your script you just create a unique output filename and copy the template:

```bsh
outfile="/path/to/$(date +%F_%T).tex"
cp /path/to/template.tex "$outfile"
```

Now you can change this file and adapt it to your needs with `sed -i`, thanks to the line marks added in comments it's easy to select single cells:

```bsh
sed -i 's/.*%A2/  replaced cell value/' "$outfile"
```

When all changes are done just run `pdflatex` on the `.tex` file to get the `.pdf` output:

```bsh
pdflatex "$outfile"
```

[image: LaTeX example 02]

#### Some links to get started with LaTeX

- Installation:

  - [How to install latex in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/932086/507051)
  - https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html
- Get started:

  - [What's the easiest way to get started with LaTeX?](https://askubuntu.com/q/501/507051)
- Find answers:

  - https://tex.stackexchange.com